# Canada - Rerouting propane heater exhaust from under deck?

Tags: heating, gas

The previous owner routed the water heater exhaust under his deck, under the patio door. It is placed 6ft from the HRV inlet.
[image]

Since it's under the patio door, I can't route it vertically. It is also less than 2" from the decking, so I can't add the 17ft it would require to vent out to the deck face, while keeping a 1/4 per foot slope.
[image]

It seems like I will need to route it 90 deg to the other deck face, but this would require cutting through 6 joists.

Is there anything which would prevent me from routing the exhaust to the other outside wall from inside the house?

Ideally, I'll want to route the furnace exhaust this way too, at some point.
[image]

Proposed routing in panorama view (there would be a 90 degree turn a bit beyond the HRV.
[image]

My main concern is that I will sort of have to MacGyver the exhaust over the HRV and then behind the sump pump outlet pipe. I don't know if I'll have the room to run all those pipes through that wall. It's the only wall I can access, as, on all other walls, there are obstacles I can't move.

On a side note, the previous owner also vented his electric clothes dryer under the decking. I've had a look at the joists, and it doesn't seem like the humidity has done anything to them.

Answer (score 2):

I will take a SWAG since you did not say I will assume they have fan driven exhaust. Calculate the length of the exhaust "tubing" including factors for bends. Upsizing it would not hurt. then check either the heater manufacturer's data to see if you fall with in there stated distance, if not do not do it. You can also contact the manufacturer to be sure. They also make inline exhaust fans you could install, I never used such a unit so you are on your own. Contacting a professional for a quote would not hurt and see how they would do it. It may be the most inexpensive and safest way in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I hadn't thought of looking for a manual for the water heater. You are correct that it's a fan driven exhaust. We'll be well within the limits for the tube length, factoring in elbows (according to the water heater, it's 5 ft less per elbow).

What I wonder is if I can vent it out next to the AC, sump and water hose outlet, as per the picture?

Answer (score 0):

You could end up with Carbon Monoxide exhausting under your deck.

It is colorless, odorless gas that is poison.

That can happen when your propane heater is not working properly, or does not have enough oxygen supply (ventilation).

In any case you should have forced exhaust (fan), to overcome the horizontal instal with 90 dgr bends for good ventilation.

Comment: You're correct. The CO is my main concern since the exhaust is so close to the HRV inlet.